# How to install AMD Radeon HD 6290 proprietary drivers in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, gpu, proprietary

I have been at this for days now. I have followed every guide that I can find. Purging and re-purging to get a clean start to try to reinstall once more but ultimately nothing has worked. I have tried installing from the package on the website as well as using apt to download fglrx. Every time I try to run fglrxinfo, I get the output of:

> X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range
>   for operation)
>   Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
>   Minor
>   opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
>   Value in failed
>   request:  0x0   Serial number of failed request:  17
>   Current serial
>   number in output stream:  18

Whenever I run amdcccle, the output says:

There was a problem initializing Catalyst Control Center Linux edition.  It could be caused by the following.

> No AMD graphics driver is installed, or the AMD driver is not
>   functioning properly. Please install the AMD driver appropriate for
>   you AMD hardware, or configure using aticonfig.

Once again, the card is an **AMD Radeon HD 6290**. I have tried to search pieces of this error with no luck of uncovering anything useful. I try very hard never to post anything to forums that is a duplicate of anything but I haven't found anything around that solves the issue I am having. Thanks.